# Bring UIButton above UIScrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I want to make a floating button inside UIViewController using uiscrollview. I try using xib before and it work, but some functionality not working when I select item. but when I use ui code it work selecting, the problem is I try to bring the button above uiscrollview like I did in xib file. but it didn't show up, please help. this is my code setup. let me know if you need to see the other uicode. thank you

```
    private func setupScrollView() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.contentSize.height = 2000

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    private func setupAbsenceBtn() {
        view.insertSubview(startAbsenceBtn, aboveSubview: scrollView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            startAbsenceBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            startAbsenceBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            startAbsenceBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55),
            startAbsenceBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 307)
        ])

    }
```

Comment: Image might be heloful in this case.

Comment: Try to add inside `scrollView` and use `bringSubviewToFront` as `scrollView.addSubView(startAbsenceBtn)` then `startAbsenceBtn.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(startAbsenceBtn)`

Comment: Add the button to the scroll view but constrain it to the scroll view's `frameLayoutGuide` instead of the `contentLayoutGuide`. It will then stay fixed as the rest of the content scrolls

Answer (score 0):

`startAbsenceBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` 
is missing.

Comment: my startAbsenceBtn is a custom button that have a default auto layout. so it's not necessary to add one, I try too with your suggestion but it still not work.

Comment: can you give the output of frame position of scrollView and button.

Comment: I try to print both scrollview and btn from frame.origin both have return value (0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0) @AbhirajKumar

Comment: It is working for me fine. Have you called  ``` setupScrollView() setupAbsenceBtn()```. Issue is only reproducible in this case.

Comment: yes it is, but I'm gonna give a thumbs up for you. since I decide to use xib. thank you @AbhirajKumar